# For Loops in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a code that will ask the user to input 3 destinations and each destination should have its own worksheet. This is what I have so far.

```
Option Explicit
'Keep the following global variables
Dim airfare As Currency
Dim hotel As Currency
Dim food As Currency
Dim destSheet As Worksheet
Dim nameDes As String

Sub travel2()

'Keep local variabels
Dim numDays As Integer
Dim namePass As String
Call Macro2

End Sub

Sub Macro2()

Const noOfDestinations As Integer = 3
Dim ThisGo As Integer

For ThisGo = 1 To noOfDestinations
    nameDes = InputBox("Please enter the destination")
    If Len(nameDes) > 0 Then

        Set destSheet = Worksheets.Add
        destSheet.Name = nameDes

    Exit For
    End If
Next ThisGo
End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a question?

Comment: Your indentation is inconsistent and makes this code harder to read. Also -- your `travel2()` sub makes no sense. All it does is declare 2 local variables which it never uses (hence effectively discarding them) and then calls some other sub. What are you trying to do? We can't read your mind.

Comment: Get rid of that `Exit For` - your user is going to enter one destination and your code will stop because of that.

Comment: I can only assume that the Sub `Travel2` is incomplete, otherwise as John says, why `Dim` something you're about to discard.

Comment: You also need some kind of test against the user's input - if a user inputs a name of a sheet that already exists, you're going to hit a run-time error and your code will break. Look into some pre-written `WorksheetExists()` functions.

Comment: Rather than 3 calls to `InputBox()` -- you could use a single one, something like "Enter destinations, separated by a comma" and then use `Split()` to extract the destinations. Popups tend to annoy users, so it is good to keep their use minimal.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my suggested fix for what I assume are your issues:

-Get rid of the `Exit For`

-Get rid of some of the "local variables" which are being used for nothing.

-Test against user input for duplicate sheets (using `SheetExists()`).

```
Option Explicit
'Keep the following global variables
Dim airfare As Currency, hotel As Currency, food As Currency
Dim destSheet As Worksheet
Dim nameDes As String
Sub travel2()

'Keep local variables
'Why???
'Dim numDays As Integer
'Dim namePass As String
Call Macro2

End Sub
Sub Macro2()

Const noOfDestinations As Integer = 3
Dim ThisGo As Integer

For ThisGo = 1 To noOfDestinations
UserEntry:
    nameDes = InputBox("Please enter the destination")

    If Len(nameDes) > 0 And SheetExists(nameDes) = False Then
        Set destSheet = Worksheets.Add
        destSheet.Name = nameDes
    Else
        MsgBox "Sheet already exists! Please try again."
        GoTo UserEntry
    End If
Next ThisGo

End Sub
Function SheetExists(shtName As String, Optional wb As Workbook) As Boolean
'Courtesy of Tim Williams
Dim sht As Worksheet

    If wb Is Nothing Then Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    On Error Resume Next
    Set sht = wb.Sheets(shtName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    SheetExists = Not sht Is Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

**Note.** GoTo statements can make code difficult to read and maintain. Whenever possible, use a control structure instead.
The above code has been modified so you use a Do...Until instead of a GoTo statement:

```
Option Explicit
'Keep the following global variables
Dim airfare As Currency, hotel As Currency, food As Currency
Dim destSheet As Worksheet
Dim nameDes As String

Sub travel2()

    'Keep local variables
    'Why???
    'Dim numDays As Integer
    'Dim namePass As String
    Call Macro2

End Sub

Sub myMacro2()

    Const noOfDestinations As Integer = 3
    Dim Counter As Integer

    Do
        nameDes = InputBox("Please enter the destination")
        If Len(nameDes) > 0 And SheetExists(nameDes) = False Then
            Set destSheet = Worksheets.Add
            destSheet.Name = nameDes
            Counter = Counter + 1
        Else
            MsgBox "Sheet already exists! Please try again."
        End If
    Loop Until Counter = noOfDestinations

End Sub

Function SheetExists(shtName As String, Optional wb As Workbook) As Boolean
    'Courtesy of Tim Williams
    Dim sht As Worksheet

    If wb Is Nothing Then Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    On Error Resume Next
    Set sht = wb.Sheets(shtName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    SheetExists = Not sht Is Nothing
End Function
```